# jquerymobile form not working as expected on mobile browsers, but works on desktop browsers?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with my jqm form not working properly in mobile browsers (iPad 1 Safari, Android Dolphin) but working as expected in desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari & IE9 on Win7).

The form starts by asking the user how they would like to be contacted (email, sms, and/or post), then updates fields to be required based on this selection (validation is via the validationEngine.js plugin).

An example of the form can be [seen here](http://coww.ws/jqmtest/).

The logic of the script is that it checks to see if the checkbox is selected (or de-selected), then adds (or removes) a class to make it required as shown below.

```
$('body').delegate('#byEmail_label', 'click tap', (function(event) {
  if (!$("#byEmail").is(":checked")) 
   {    
        $('#req_email').addClass('reqField');
        $('#email').addClass("validate[required,custom[email]]");
  }
  else
   { 
        $('#req_email').removeClass('reqField');
        $('#email').removeClass("validate[required,custom[email]]").validationEngine('hide');   
  }
})
);
```

I had this working 100% without the .delegate(), but then I could not have the form load via ajax - after adding .delegate it all works well, except in mobile browsers.

Has anyone experienced something similar, or have any idea how I can get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed my own problem by moving all my jquery outside the

```
 $(document).ready(function () {...
```

and into

```
$('*').delegate('body','pagecreate', function(){...
```

ie:

```
$('*').delegate('body','pagecreate', function(){
  $('#byEmail_label').tap(function(event) {
    if ($("#byEmail").is(":checked"))
     {
    $('#req_email').addClass('reqField');
    $('#email').addClass("validate[required,custom[email]]");
     }
     else
     {
    $('#req_email').removeClass('reqField');
    $('#email').removeClass("validate[required,custom[email]]").validationEngine('hide');
     }
  });
});
```

Now my head feels better... no more banging it on the desk...

Answer (score 0):

I also had troubles with checkboxes and radios, this is what I used. Might help to check for the value instead of if it's checked.

```
alert($('input[name=byEmail]:checked').val());
```

or

```
var cb_val = $('input[name=byEmail]:checked').val() == true;
```

or

```
var cb_val = ($('input[name=byEmail]:checked').val() == 'blah') ? true:false;
```

Maybe something like this

```
var addValidation = ($('input[name=byEmail]:checked').val() != '') ? true:false;

if(addValidation) {    
    $('#req_email').addClass('reqField');
    $('#email').addClass("validate[required,custom[email]]");
} else { 
    $('#req_email').removeClass('reqField');
    $('#email').removeClass("validate[required,custom[email]]").validationEngine('hide');   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Phill, annoyingly the code works fine without the .delegate() and the ajax page load. ie. ` $('#byEmail_label').tap(function(event) {
   if ($("#byEmail").is(":checked")) 
    {  
   $('#req_email').addClass('reqField');
   $('#email').addClass("validate[required,custom[email]]");
   }
   else
    { 
    $('#req_email').removeClass('reqField');
   $('#email').removeClass("validate[required,custom[email]]").validationEngine('hide'); 
   }
 });`